# Como trabalhar com assincronismo usando o ReactJS

Tags: javascript, api, firebase, react, assincronismo

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
requireUsers = () => {
    this.users = database.ref('users')
    this.users.on('value', snapshot => {
        this.state.users = snapshot.val()
        Object.keys(snapshot.val()).map((value,key) => emails[key] = snapshot.val()[value].email)  
    })       
}

requireSeries = () => {
    Object.keys(emails).map((value,key) => emails[value] === email ? userId = Object.keys(this.state.users)[key] : "")
    this.series = database.ref(`users/${userId}/series/${this.props.match.params.genre}`)
    this.series.on('value', snapshot => {
        this.setState({
            series: snapshot.val()
        })
    })
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user){
            email = user.email   
            this.setState({
                isLoggedIn: true,
                isLoading: false
            })              
            this.requireUsers()
            window.setTimeout(this.requireSeries, 2000)  
        }
    })         
}
```

Sei que essa função `window.setTimeout(this.requireSeries, 2000)` vai dar pau alguma hora, quando o número de registro de usuários for grande, mas é a unica maneira que encontrei para carregar os dados no `this.state.users`. Tentei usar `async` e `await` mas não funcionou. Alguém sabe como usaria `async` / `await` aí?

Answer (score 2):

Como você tentou usar `async` e `await`? await é uma palavra reservada que serve para esperar uma `Promise` ser resolvida, se você não criar promises, não tem como usar await.

async por outro lado serve como um modificador de função. Ele faz com que todos os retornos de uma função se transforme em um `Promise.resove`, e todos os erros em um `Promise.reject`, ou seja, é açúcar sintático.

Porém se você tem muitas funções aninhadas é mais fácil trabalhar com a sintaxe clássica, especialmente se você quiser retornar um resultado.

A jugar pelo seu código, acredito que sintaxe seria assim:

```
requireUsers = () => new Promise((resolve , reject) => {
    this.users = database.ref('users');
    this.users.on('value', snapshot => {
        this.state.users = snapshot.val();
        Object.keys(snapshot.val()).map((value,key) => emails[key] = snapshot.val()[value].email);
        resolve(/*você pode retornar um valor aqui*/);
    });
});
```

Com async e await ficaria dessa forma:

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
        if (user) {
            email = user.email; 
            this.setState({
                isLoggedIn: true,
                isLoading: false
            });              
            await this.requireUsers();
            this.requireSeries();
        }
    });
}
```

Agora se por alguma razão async e await não funcionar, porque seu framework está rodando funções síncronas por trás dos callbacks, você terá que usar os métodos `then` e `catch`, que são infalíveis:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
            email = user.email; 
            this.setState({
                isLoggedIn: true,
                isLoading: false
            });
            /*v é o valor que você retornou, é irrelevante nesse exemplo*/
            this.requireUsers().then(v => this.requireSeries());
        }
    });
}
```